# C# array of button not working

Tags: c#, button

I am currently quite desperate as I have been stuck on a problem for a significant amount of time in visual c# 2010. I'm trying to a button in form an a form application. The button a defined by a polygon.

```
Button target_east = new Button ();

Point[] pts_East = {
    new Point(20, 10),  new Point(80, 10), new Point(80, 40),
    new Point(90, 40),  new Point(90, 60), new Point(80, 60),
    new Point(80, 90),  new Point(20, 90)
};

GraphicsPath polygon_West_path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);

Region polygon_region_east = new Region(polygon_path_east);

polygon_path_east.AddPolygon(pts_East);
```

case 'B':

```
target_east.Region = polygon_region_east;
target_east.BackColor = Color.Red;

// Make the button big enough to hold the whole region.
target_east.SetBounds(
target_east.Location.X,
target_east.Location.Y - 40,
pts_East[3].X + 5, pts_East[6].Y + 5);

rows = (numbers[counter] / 10);
columns = 10 - (numbers[counter] - rows * 10);

target_east.Location = new Point((rows * 60 + 255), (columns * 60) + 20);
target_east.Text = "B" + Convert.ToString(numbers[counter]);
target_east.BringToFront();
target_east.Parent = this;
counter++;

break;
```

this give no error, however it doesn't show it on screen.
I would appreciate any suggestion or help.
Thank you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you need to add the button to the parent's `Controls` list?

Comment: and what is `polygon_path_east`?

Comment: @GrawCube, `target_east.Parent = this;` produce the same result as `this.Controls.Add(target_east);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I have added Parent.Controls.Add(target_east); it's no not displaying the button.

Comment: @ASh Oh, I see! I just checked the [reference source page](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,ef716beee4738662,references) - looks like it calls `value.Controls.Add`!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I have solved it by initializing the button properly